# mi Datatable me da un error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatables

al crear mi tabla si me ejecuta con datatable con el buscador y paginación pero me da lanza un error

aqui les dejo mi tabla:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="tblInventario" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Matricula</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Ubicación</th>
                        <th>imagen</th>
                        <th>editar</th>
                        <th>eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
```

y aqui esta mi script que este en el mismo archivo php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable = $('#tblInventario').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "order": [],
                "ajax": {
                    url: "obtenerRegistros.php",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                "columnsDefs": [{
                    "targets": [0, 3, 4],
                    "orderable": false,
                }, ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

y me lanza esta alerta

***DataTables warning: table id=tblInventario - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1***

Comment: _Invalid JSON response_: ¿el servidor está devolviendo un JSON válido? ¿Hiciste lo que se indica en el enlace del error?

Comment: El error es claro, el servidor está devolviendo un JSON no válido. Antes de procesar la Datatable, mejor debbugea en PHP puro. Pueda que desde la llamada a la base tengas un error y no lo veas porque la única salida es la del Datatable. Siempre siempre debes debbugear tu código.